# .inc Files in PHP

Tags: php, comments

To avoid hacking I created an admin page in ad-min.php.inc where you can login.
When I try to access ad-min.php.inc all my php script is commented:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

Ends up in the broswer blank with:

```
<!--<?php
echo "Hello";
?>-->
```

How could I fix this? On my local computer everything work (on a Mac) but when I set it up in the server it doesn't work. Thank you, sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: you're web server isn't set up to parse .inc files correctly.

Comment: how does this "avoid hacking" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are running into is that your page doesn't have a *.php extension, meaning the server doesn't know how to interpret it, or that it is a PHP script.

Three ways to fix this:

Setup a mime-type in your .htaccess file to have .inc files interpreted as PHP:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .inc
```

Otherwise you can include the file in another file with a *.php extension:

```
<?php include('ad-min.php.inc'); ?>
```

Or simply rename the file to be ad-min.php

Best of luck!